# workflow using visual studio

Tags: workflow

I am creating a project.In that i created one Custom list.Now i want to create a workflow using visual studio 2008.The workflow has to send an email who entered data to that list.That will be rejected or Approved status. Basically i am creating it for Travel fare claim.

How do I approach this?

Comment: Sounds like a cool workflow! What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to create one - Sharepoint 2010 has a built-in approval workflow that supports email notifications.

For more details, see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/understand-approval-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010-HA101857172.aspx